# Count for each item and for each month within a date range the number of items that are in the inventory - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table *T1* with 3 columns: *ProductBrand*, *PurchasedDate*, *SoldDate*. *ProductBrand* represents the brand of the product. *PurchasedDate*  contains the date (in format yyyy-mm) when we purchased a product and *SoldDate* contains the date (again in yyyy-mm) when we sold this product. For example:

```
ProductBrand  PurchasedDate  SoldDate
----------------------------------
Apple          2015-03      2015-05
Samsung        2014-01      2015-03
Sony           2016-02      2016-05 
Sony           2013-01      2013-08 
Apple          2015-05      2015-10 
LG             2011-02      2014-06 
Samsung        2017-02      2017-04 
LG             2016-01      2016-06 
LG             2018-06      2019-01
```

I would like a table that counts for each brand and for each month (between the years 2010-01 and 2019-12) how many products of this specific brand I had for this particular month in the inventory. Namely, in this example, I have two Apple products. The first one stayed in the inventory between 2015-03 and 2015-06 and the second one stayed in the inventory between 2015-04 and 2015-08. So I expect a table that has:

```
ProductBrand  YearMonthDate  NitemsInventory
------------  ------------   -------------------
Apple         2010-01               0
Apple         2010-02               0
...            ...                 ... 
Apple         2015-03               1
Apple         2015-04               2
Apple         2015-05               2
Apple         2015-06               2
Apple         2015-07               1
Apple         2015-08               1
Apple         2015-09               0
...            ...                 ...
Apple         2019-12               0
```

In the same table I would like to have all the brands in the same fashion as Apple. So if we have **n** different brands and **t** is the number of months between (2010-01 and 2019-12), the end array will have **n times t** rows. In other words, I would like see for each month the number of items that I had in the inventory for each brand.

I am using mysql and I suppose I have tried to groupby the column ProductBrand  of T1. However, this does not give what I expect.

Comment: Do you have a table of dates... or numbers?

Comment: You first need a table of all the months you want. Then left join the inventory table to that when the month is within the range of the inventory table. Group by the month and brand and take the count.

Comment: In the example you have mentioned "The first one stayed in the inventory between 2015-03 and 2015-06 and the second one stayed in the inventory between 2015-04 and 2015-08. " but first one has sold date as  '2015-5' and second one has 2015-10. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with some big ugly calendar tables:

```
SELECT
    t.ProductBrand,
    d.YearMonthDate,
    COUNT(t.ProductBrand) AS NitemsInventory
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ProductBrand FROM yourTable
) AS p
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT '2010-01' AS YearMonthDate UNION ALL
    SELECT '2010-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2010-03' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2015-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-04' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2019-12'
) AS d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.YearMonthDate BETWEEN t.PurchasedDate AND t.SoldDate AND
       p.ProductBrand = t.ProductBrand
WHERE
    t.productBrand IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    t.ProductBrand,
    d.YearMonthDate;
```

Here is a demo which shows the query in action:

### Demo

Comment: I have around 30 brands and I would like if possible not to hardcode each individual brand. You may assume that we can take the unique values of productbrands and use that as a list of the different products.

Comment: I have made the suggested change.  But, you still might be stuck with having to use a calendar table, unless you are certain that your data table would always have an entry for each year-month combination.

Comment: It will have. Is there any way using iteration to create all months between these two years?

Comment: @mars I have given you a working demo above.  Please research on "calendar table MySQL" to find ways to generate your date calendar table.

Comment: I would like not to have nan values on the first column of the result table